# Solving Josephus permutation

Tags: r, for-loop

> Suppose if 100 people standing in a circle in an order 1 to 100. No. 1 has a sword. He kills the next person (i.e. No. 2) and gives the sword to the next (i.e. No. 3). All people do the same until only 1 survives. Which number survives at the last?

There are 100 people starting from 1 to 100.

I tried with

```
persons <- c(1:100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  qu <- persons[seq_along(persons) %% 2 > 0]
  if (q2 == 2) {
    print(q2[2])
  }
}
```

and also with this

```
q=0
 while(q==0){ persons=persons[seq_along(persons) %% 2 > 0]
 if(length(persons)==2){ print(persons[2])
 q=1}}
```

But this gives an answer as 65 which is wrong and doesn't solve the purpose.

Any solution how this could be done?

Comment: Just for the note, this problem is called [the Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this solution, assume the person with the sword is the first person in the vector. That person kills the next person and moves to the end of the line.

If there is one person, then that person is the survivor.

```
kill <- function(people = seq_len(100)) {
  if (length(people) == 1) return(people)

  kill(
    c(tail(people, -2), people[1]))
}


kill()
#> [1] 73
```

Edit:

For large `n`, use the following [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#k=2)

```
kill_fast <- function(n) 2 * (n - 2 ^ (floor(log2(n)))) + 1

kill_fast(100)
#> [1] 73

kill_fast(100000)
#> [1] 68929
```

Comment: yes that the correct answer. if you could please elaborate your code inside `if statement`

Comment: The if statement is just checking if there is only one person left. If there is, then we return that person.

Otherwise, the first two people are removed and the old first person gets added to the end. Then the same function gets applied to this new set of people.

Answer (score 5):

Here's @Paul's elegant answer rewritten in a non-recursive way, so it is maybe easier to understand.

```
people <- 1:100
while (length(people) > 1) {
  people <- c(people[-(1:2)], people[1])
}
print(people)
# [1] 73
```

Answer (score 2):

That leaves one alive but I am not sure about the problem constraints

```
persons=rep("ALIVE",100)
for(i in 1:100) {
  if(i+1<101){
    if(persons[i+1]=="ALIVE"){
      persons[i]<-"DEAD"
    }
  }
  print(persons)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not like I don't like recursion, but here is a more universal solution, which works for any population size:

```
kill <- function(n = 100) {
  seq1 <- 2 ^ seq_len(31)
  seq2 <- n / seq1
  seq2 <- c(n, floor(seq2[seq2 >= 3]))
  sum(seq1[1:length(seq2)][seq2 %% 2 == 1], 1)
}
```

Now you can see that if we would play this among us roughly 8 million Swissies , I should line up at position `7'611'393`... (`kill(8000000)`)